# creating function for loading conf file and store all properties in case class

Tags: scala

I have one app.conf file like below:

```
some_variable_a = some_infohere_a  
some_variable_b = some_infohere_b
```

Now I need to write scala function to load this app.conf file and create a scala case class to store all these properties. with try-catch and file checking conditions and corner cases.

I am very new to scala do not have much knowledge on this please provide me a correct way to do this.

Whatever I tried I am writing below:

```
import java.io.File
import com.typesafe.config.{ Config, ConfigFactory }
import com.typesafe.config._
import java.nio.file.Paths


private def ReadConfFile(path: String) = {   
val fileTemp = new File(path)  
  if (fileTemp.exists) {      


val confFile = Paths.get(Path).toFile
val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile)
val some_variable_a = config.getString("some_variable_a")
val some_variable_b = config.getString("some_variable_b")


     }  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [pureconfig](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/)?

Comment: no, actually i don't know about that

Comment: @jwvh I understand whatever you are saying that might be correct approach, but I got the above requirement and need to do it that way only, If you have any clue please guide me

Comment: Does your posted code work? Are you able to get the `some_variable` values? If not then this business about a case class is pointless. Show us the error you're getting when trying to load the config file. If the code _does_ work then this business about config values is pointless. You just need to define a case class and create an instance with the retrieved values. So which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that app.conf is in root folder of your application, this should be enough to access those variables from config file:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("app.conf")
val some_variable_a = config.getString("some_variable_a")
val some_variable_b = config.getString("some_variable_b")
```

In case you need to load it from the file using absolute path, you can do that in this way:

```
val myConfigFile = new File("/home/user/location/app.conf")
val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(myConfigFile)
val some_variable_a = config.getString("some_variable_a")
val some_variable_b = config.getString("some_variable_b")
```

Or something similar as you did. In your code there is a typo I guess in Paths.get(Path).toFile. "Path" should be "path". If you If you don't have some variable Path, you should get compiling error for that. If that is not the problem, then check if you are providing correct path:

```
private def ReadConfFile(path: String) = {
    val fileTemp = new File(path)
    if (fileTemp.exists) {
      val confFile = Paths.get(path).toFile
      val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile)
      val some_variable_a = config.getString("some_variable_a")
      val some_variable_b = config.getString("some_variable_b")
    }
}
ReadConfFile("/home/user/location/app.conf")
```

Comment: thanks for the respons, my app.conf will be at temp location and I need to write function for to load conf file and create case class to store those properties, how to do it can you please suggest. with some code here,